# I need report on chat system created in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created chat system in firebase and now i want report on daily,weekly,monthly that how many users are exchaging how many words and how much time they are engaged with app,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some reporting of message delivery in the [Firebase Cloud Messaging console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification/reporting).

If that isn't enough for your needs, you may want to connect [Firebase Cloud Messaging to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#bigquery_data_export). After you do this, Firebase will write delivery data into BigQuery, where you can query it. The documentation includes some example queries to get you started.